# How to properly JSON encode/decode a Duration field in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am using convert package for the following task:

```
factory Brick.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Brick(
      title: json['title'],
      expectedDuration: json['expected_duration'],
    );
  }


Future<Brick> createBrick(
      String title, Duration expDur) async {
    var url = 'https://api.com/bricks/';
    
    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
      body: convert.jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "title": "$title",
        "expected_duration": expDur,
      }),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      Brick newBrick = Brick.fromJson(convert.jsonDecode(response.body));
      notifyListeners();
      return newBrick;
    } else {
      throw Exception(
          '${response.statusCode} ${response.reasonPhrase}');
    }
  }
```

When I call the createBrick function, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Duration'

How should I convert Duration? There's no mention of it on the Duration class documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add json response?

Comment: @Priyesh actually there's no JSON response, as the code fails when running convert.jsonEncode.

Comment: A duration value has no literal representation in the JSON specification. You might as well have asked about anything else. For example, about complex numbers or solar cycles in JSON.

Comment: @Priyesh if I modify expDur - inside the http post - to "$expDur" then the JSON response is 200 (and the brick does get posted through the API) but I get the exception "Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Duration')" inside factory Brick.fromJSON at expectedDuration line.

Comment: you can try `expectedDuration  : Duration(seconds: int.parse(json['excepted_duration']))` for convert your string to Duration

Answer (score 6):

You can put into JSON seconds (or milliseconds, depends on your features) from `Duration`:

```dart
'expected_duration': expDur.inSeconds,
```

And work with `expected_duration` as seconds:

```dart
expectedDuration: Duration(seconds: json['excepted_duration']),
```

If you have a duration that less than one second (milliseconds), you should to use milliseconds instead of seconds.